# My jQuery, AJAX call is getting a null response on a valid return of well-formatted JSON data from a PHP function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, google-chrome

I have checked the logs of my PHP function and I have correctly formatted JSON data that I am returning from the method.  The AJAX is calling it and returning, getting a null value for the response variable.  Any Ideas?  Here is the AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "index.php/controllerFile/get_standby",
       data: 'id=' + $(this).attr('id'),
       success: function(response){  


             console.log('response is: ' + response); //It is null here
         $.colorbox({'href':'index.php/config/view/standby' + response.urlData,'width':1000,'title':'Standby People'});         
       },

       dataType:'json'
     });
```

Here is the PHP function:

```
function get_standby()
    {

        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $this->load->model('teetime');
        $url['urlData'] = ($this->teetime->get_standby_by_id($id));

        $printing = json_encode($url);
        log_message('error', 'JSON ' . $printing);
        return $printing;

    }
```

Comment: You are printing it out somewhere else in the PHP code, right (given that `get_standby` just returns the string, it doesn't print it out)?

Comment: The log command prints the string to the log file, but I never actually printed it in my php code. I found out I needed to echo the json.Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using echo in your PHP instead of return.

```
echo $printing;
```

Comment: That was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest opening up Developer Tools in Chrome (View > Developer > Developer Tools) and selecting the Network tab. When your AJAX post request is made, it should add an entry there (the "Path" column should be "index.php/controllerFile/get_standby" and the "Method" column should have "POST"). Click the row for the request and check the Response tab to make sure your JSON is there.

If the response is empty, your problem is with your PHP code (you might not be printing the JSON returned from that function to the page). Otherwise, it would seemingly be a problem with your JavaScript.